# Run script in a non interactive shell?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, cron, interactive

I have a cron job that is running a script. When I run the script via an interactive shell (ssh'ed to bash) it works fine. When the script runs by itself via cron it fails.

My guess is that it is using some of the environmental variables set in the interactive shell. I'm going to troubleshoot the script and remove these.

After I make changes, I know I could queue up the script in cron to have it run as it would normally, but **is there a way I can run the script from the command line, but tell it to run as it would from cron - i.e. in a non-interactive environment?**

Comment: Related and thus possibly helpful: ["How to get a clean environment in a ksh shell?"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23822/how-to-get-a-clean-environment-in-a-ksh-shell/23823#23823) see especially @Gilles answer regarding `unset`.

Comment: From @sr_'s link, I looked up `env`, and you might want to try `env -i ./my-script.sh`.  Also, are you getting an error message?

Comment: What cron implementation are you using?

Comment: @kevin - i'll upvote that if you answer with it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The main differences between running a command from cron and running on the command line are:

- cron is probably using a different shell (generally `/bin/sh`);
- cron is definitely running in a small environment (which ones depends on the cron implementation, so check the `cron(8)` or `crontab(5)` man page; generally there's just `HOME`, perhaps `SHELL`, perhaps `LOGNAME`, perhaps `USER`, and a small `PATH`);
- cron treats the `%` character specially (it is turned into a newline);
- cron jobs run without a terminal or graphical environment.

The following invocation will run the shell snippet pretty much as if it was invoked from cron. I assume the snippet doesn't contain the characters `'` or `%`.

```
env - HOME="$HOME" USER="$USER" PATH=/usr/bin:/bin /bin/sh -c 'shell snippet' </dev/null >job.log 2>&1
```

See also [executing a sh script from the cron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6790/executing-a-sh-script-from-the-cron), which might help solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @Giles - just thought of something - would running a script like `sudo -u user /path/to/script` also be a way to run it without any variables set?

Comment: @cwd No, usually not. `sudo` clears some variables and sets others to a known value, but that depends on how it's configured. It is often configured to retain locale settings and `TERM`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

To run your script in a non-interactive shell (not regarding the details of `cron`), you can do this via `ssh`.

Test if you really end up in a non-interactive shell:

```
> ssh someuser@somehost tty
not a tty
```

Execute the script in a non-interactive shell:

```
> ssh someuser@somehost /tmp/myscript.sh
```

Comment: This is the only method that created a non-interactive shell

Answer (score 2):

From @sr_'s link ([How to get a clean environment in a ksh shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23822/how-to-get-a-clean-environment-in-a-ksh-shell/23823#23823)), I looked up env, and you might want to try this:

```
env -i ./my-script.sh
```

Comment: This worked well for me although @Gilles answer is also really good.

Comment: @cwd: Doesn't work for me: `echo -e '#!/bin/bash -i\necho interactive $-' > ~/test.sh && chmod +x ~/test.sh && env -i ~/test.sh` outputs `interactive himB`.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to ignore some interactive questions provided by some script, you can try:

```
yes | your_command
```

Or `yes "n"` if you'd like to No all the questions.

> Command:
>
> yes -- be repetitively affirmative yes outputs expletive, or, by default, 'y', forever.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use absolute paths for your scripts when putting it in cron and using elsewhere and for any and all linux commands used in it, better declare them as variables and use it thereof!

Comment: yes. but of course.

Answer (score 0):

Cron doesn't necessarily use the same shell you are using.  check:

```
cat /etc/crontab |grep SHELL
```

To determine the shell and attempt execution of your script there - does it work? This is a common cause of issues for many people adding scripts to cron.

If this is the problem - you can add "bash" to the beginning of your script in cron to force this script to execute in bash.  If this does not solve the issue, let me know and I'll dig a little deeper.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are useful for simulating other details of cron, but if you're specifically looking to simulate non-interactive execution, in most cases you're looking for [setsid](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setsid.1.html).

`setsid <command>` will run `<command>` independently, with no associated parent process or terminal, very closely simulating an environment where there was never a parent interactive terminal at all.

It won't isolate the command in many others ways though, so if you want to unset environment variables and so on (as in the other answers here) you'll want to simulate that too.