# How to start a process chain from the shell

Tags: bash, shell, namespace

Is it possible and if so how do I:

1. Start a `/bin/bash` process that is not bound to a terminal from a terminal?
   Hence, a shell process that shows up in the process tree as
   `init -- bash`. (Shells usually have the process tree structure `terminal-emulator-of-your-choosing -- bash`)
2. Start a `/bin/bash` process not bound to a terminal that has as its child another process e.g. a browser like `firefox` from a shell session in a terminal? Hence, a shell process with a child that shows up in the process tree as `init -- bash -- firefox`.
3. It is easy to get `init -- firefox` directly from the shell via something along the lines of `exec firefox & exit` or `/bin/bash -c firefox & exit`.

(This question is part of a series of related questions that first enabled me to formulate these questions precisely (cf. [How to "correctly" start an application from a shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152310/how-to-correctly-start-an-application-from-a-shell) and [Is reparenting from the shell possible?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152379/how-to-start-a-process-from-the-shell-and-make-it-the-child-of-another-process)). The three questions have been formulated and discussed partially in the comments of the two former questions but as I see it not been answered. Furthermore, they do seem more appropriate as short question in their own right not suited for discussion in comments.)

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. There, now the "Is it possible" part is answered. How is another beast altogether.

Comment: Yeah, I learned that the hard way... I tried and tried and searching the internet is not helpful either...

Comment: Try `setsid sh -c 'firefox&' <> /dev/null >&0 2>&0` (note that it makes it immune to SIGINTs)

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68574/22565

Comment: And http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56510/22565

Comment: Sorry `setsid bash -c 'firefox; exit'` if you actually want `init -- bash -- firefox` not connected to a terminal (`setsid sh -c 'bash -c "firefox; exit" &'` to make sure that `bash` doesn't get control of a terminal if it ever opens one).

Comment: Hm, `setsid` making the process immune to SIGINTS worries me. Actually the [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56495/whats-the-difference-between-running-a-program-as-a-daemon-and-forking-it-into/56510#56510) you provided contains a command that does exactly what I want: `(trap '' HUP; command) &`. Do you have an opinion on that (possible problems etc.?)

Comment: In what way do your `setsid` commands make the process immune to SIGINTs? If i use `kill -15 PID-of-firefox` on the instances of firefox I started with your commands they exit cleanly.

Comment: Or did you just mean immune to SIGINTS when I'm exiting the terminal?

Comment: @lord.garbage `(trap '' HUP; command) &` still results in a process bound to a terminal (at least until the interactive shell you started it from exits). Is that what you want?

Comment: What I want is complete when I have exited the shell just as you said. So the whole command I want is `(trap '' HUP; command) & exit`.

Comment: @Stéphane, would you care to turn this into a concise answer?

Comment: @lord.garbage, that's not `setsid` making processes immune to SIGINT (though it does make it immune to CTRL-C by detaching from the terminal). It's running a job in background from a subshell that does. The `setsid()` system call is the only way one can detach from a terminal.

Comment: Do you need GNU bash? Because [`mksh`](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/mksh) has that feature built in. Run `mksh -T/dev/tty10` to open one on that tty, `mksh -T- -c 'command; command; …'` to run dæmonised. (Full disclosure: I’m the [`mksh`](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) developer.)